# 404 errors in Joomla backend

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator

I've a problem in the back end for Joomla. I am moving my web site to a new server; it's not ready to go live yet. The problem happens all over the place not just in Article manager but here's an example.

I list articles in Article Manager. I hover over the title one of the articles and it reads:

http://{ip address}/plesk-site-preview/test.{site}.org.uk/http/{ip address}/administrator/index.php?option=com_content&task=article.edit&id=1551

I then click on the title. It should open up the article for editing but instead returns a 404 error. The URL it was attempting to execute reads:

http://{ip address}/administrator/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&layout=edit&id=1551

So it's dropping part of the URL reviled when I hover over the link.

I haven't changed any SEF settings. I don't get this behaviour on the old web site or on my localhost as there the URLs are identical.

Any thoughts please?

Regards

Comment: I should have said that the joomla version is 3.10.11

Comment: You may [edit] relevant information into your question at any time and as many times as you need.  Please fix "reviled" and remove "Regards" when you edit.